# Using GenericQueue to print words input by user in reverse order. Java

Tags: java, queue, stack

I am confused with the GenericQueue. With only add elements (queue.enqueue) and remove elements (queue.dequque) from it, how can I display a reverse words from user input?

To be more specific, I have the following code for java.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class displayreverse {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        GenericQueue<String> queue = new GenericQueue<String>();
        System.out.print("Enter some words: ");
        String words = input.nextLine();

        queue.enqueue(words);
        System.out.println(queue);

    }
}
```

The output will look like this:

```
run:
Enter some words: who are you
Queue; [who are you]
```

How will I use the GenericQueue in order for it to display it in reverse order? The output should be like: "you are who" instead of "who are you"

My GenericQueue class is as follows:

```
public class GenericQueue<E> {
    private java.util.LinkedList<E> list = new java.util.LinkedList<E>();
            public void enqueue(E e){
                list.addLast(e);
            }
            public E dequeue(){
                return list.removeFirst();
            }
            public int getSize(){
                return list.size();
            }
            public String toString(){
                return "Queue; " + list.toString();
            }
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: Why are you using a GenericQueue, typically to reverse you'd use a stack because of it's Last In First Out (LIFO) ordering. Whereas a Queue is First In First Out (FIFO). Perhaps extend the GenericQueue class with your own class that implements the addItem function to add to the front of the list instead of the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `enqueueFirst` method in `GenericQueue` as add the elements in front(or change `enqueue` to add in front not last)

```
  public void enqueueFirst(E e){
    list.addFirst(e);
  }
```

For receiving the words all in same line using `enqueueFirst` as below:

```
    System.out.print("Enter some words: ");
    String wordsLine = input.nextLine();
    String[] words  = wordsLine.split(" ");//split the words separated by space
    for(String word: words){
        queue.enqueueFirst(word);//add one word at a time
    }
```

Rest looks fine.